# Invalid HTTP Request - linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

Tags: linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

Suddenly linkedin oauth2 stopped working! As per instructions found here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

When invoking this:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75jdo0an3ktnbx&redirect_uri=https://app.myapp.com/account/linkedin_login&state=fregfdgfasd&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress

Instead of a valid response I get a 400 error:

LinkedIn
Invalid HTTP Request
Could not process this client request HTTP method request for URL. Please double-check the URL (address) you used, or contact us if you feel you have reached this page in error.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem using Chrome, but not with Edge or Firefox.  Contacted LI, reply was we are working on it, no estimate of when we will solve it. The new profile update seems to be botched in Chrome, OK with Edge and still not updated to the new look if using Firefox.

Linkedin has problems far deeper than poor coding, they forgot the meaning of being social in networking, the site is becoming a pile of stale resumes, non-existent debates and bad quality networking.

Comment: The same problem occurs on Firefox & Edge for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not OAuth fluent enough to tell you why, but they have 2 different systems: oAuth and oAuth legacy.
I personaly couldn't find a way to retrieve a valid token from OAuth but yes from OAuth legacy. The main difference is the URL and the authorization window.

You are actually using : https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2 for you api calls.
OAuth legacy is using https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2.

The whole process is the same so you won't have to change your code, just the URL.

see OAuth legacy doc: linkedin.com/docs/oauth2-legacy

The bad side is the authorization window, the user has to literaly login (email + password) before clicking on the 'Authorized' button and being redirected to your callback URL.

I am agree, this website has something buggy. When visited from France (browser language set to FR-fr and an IP geolocalised in France), their whole interface is written in Dutch ...

Anyway, i hope it helps